# Play/search a Shout Cast FM station on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: media

I am mainly looking for Tamil and Hindi channels. Is there any player for Ubuntu which will allow me to search for Tamil and Hindi language FM stations and stream on my PC ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Banshee Media Player with its add-ons, it's available at Ubuntu Software Center. I just checked there's Hindi radio available. You can also visit their [official website](http://banshee.fm/)

Comment: Thanks Vladdy. I will check and update. So nice of you to help, I think I have Banshee MP installed on my PC.

Comment: I tried but was unable to find a list of radio station. Mind sharing the path for it on Banshee MP please ? Thanks.

Comment: it looks like in this [picture](http://pasteboard.co/1MEarhzU.png) if you don't find any live radio tabs check the extensions if you activated them, in bunshee go to edit/preferences/extensions and tick the services that you'd like to use, any additional addons and extensions you can find using Synaptic Manager.